# QGIS form action that allows the user to select a feature from another layer to set a field

Tags: pyqgis, actions, attribute-form

I'm trying to create a QGIS action that will be used on an attribute form to get a value from a feature on another target layer and set a field on the current form. I have it mostly working (based heavily on [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/371172/120481)) in that I can click the button on the form, select a feature, and update the current feature, but I can't get the form's input to update with the new value. What I've got:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.PyQt import QtWidgets

TARGET_LAYER_NAME = "Layer_Name"  # Change this string to click a different layer
TARGET_FEATURE_NAME = "attribute_name_from"  # Change this to change field copied
CURRENT_FEATURE_NAME = "attribute_name_to"  # Change this to change which field is updated
_current_layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayer("[%@layer_id%]")
_tool = iface.mapCanvas().mapTool()  # Get the current tool so we can set it back

class selectTool(QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature):
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        self.layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(TARGET_LAYER_NAME)[0]
        QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature.__init__(self, self.canvas, self.layer)

    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        found_features = self.identify(event.x(), event.y(), [self.layer], QgsMapToolIdentify.TopDownAll)
        if len(found_features) < 1:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, "Missed!", f"Please select a feature in the {TARGET_LAYER_NAME} layer.")

        elif len(found_features) == 1:
            current_id = [% @id %]
            target_feature = found_features[0]
            target_value = target_feature.mFeature[TARGET_FEATURE_NAME]
            # Set the field
            _current_layer.changeAttributeValue(current_id, _current_layer.fields().lookupField(CURRENT_FEATURE_NAME), target_value)
            # Notify and reset tool
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, "Updated", f"Set {current_id} {CURRENT_FEATURE_NAME} to {target_value}")
            iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(_tool)

        else:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, "Too many!", f"Please only select one feature in the {TARGET_LAYER_NAME} layer.")

t = selectTool(iface)
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(t)
```

The action has default python setup:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add [`_current_layer.reload()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.reload) to your `canvasPressEvent` method like so:

```py
def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
    found_features = self.identify(event.x(), event.y(), [self.layer], QgsMapToolIdentify.TopDownAll)
    if len(found_features) < 1:
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, "Missed!", f"Please select a feature in the {TARGET_LAYER_NAME} layer.")

    elif len(found_features) == 1:
        current_id = [% @id %]
        target_feature = found_features[0]
        target_value = target_feature.mFeature[TARGET_FEATURE_NAME]
        # Set the field
        _current_layer.changeAttributeValue(current_id, _current_layer.fields().lookupField(CURRENT_FEATURE_NAME), target_value)
        # Notify and reset tool
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, "Updated", f"Set {current_id} {CURRENT_FEATURE_NAME} to {target_value}")
        iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(_tool)

        # ---- this should update the form ----
        _current_layer.reload()

    else:
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, "Too many!", f"Please only select one feature in the {TARGET_LAYER_NAME} layer.")
```